# Adding button on google map V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to allow user to set the google map view manually,

```
GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE
GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN
GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE
```

so I need to set some button on google map. How to do it? is there any option in Google Map API ? I am using `GoogleMap googleMap;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sn.orange.mobile.senmap) I added a menu item in the action bar and I used the `changeMapType` method below to switch the map type.

You can add a button also on the map by using a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`, like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- this layout will contain your map fragment -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:centerVertical="true"
        android:alignParentLeft="true" >
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`changeMapType` method :

```
public void changeMapType() {
    if (map != null) {
        int type = map.getMapType();
        switch (type) {
        case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.mapTypeSatellite, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.mapTypeStreet,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.mapTypeHybrid,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID:
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.mapTypeNormal,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked exactly as described.  Thanks.  Note that you need to have both of the Relative Layouts as shown above.  I did it using a MapView rather than a MapFragment.

Answer (score 2):

Draw your GoogleMap fragment in a **RelativeLayout** and and any button or view above or anywhere relative to it.

This should be simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to add buttons on top of map, like Google does with the myLocation Button. I suggest you use RelativeLayout on your xml, and customize some buttons to be a little transparent, then put them on top of the map, here is my code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/actualiser"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_actualiser" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actualiser"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_add" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

As you can see, I added two buttons and a progress bar that shows on top of the map, and with some transparency on the buttons backgrounds, you will get what you want.